# Ribbon not available for list item in dynamically created XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: web-part, ribbon, xslt-list-view-web-part

The situation is the following. I'm creating an XsltListViewWebPart during the Page LifeCycle which is added to the page Controls collection (or UserControl Controls collection). The XsltListViewWebPart is displayed as expected.
The only problem is that when an item is selected, the "List Tools" ribbon tab is not available (not visible).

```
XsltListViewWebPart lvwp = new XsltListViewWebPart();    
SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = thisWeb.GetList(SPUtility.ConcatUrls(thisWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, "lists/" + listName));
SPView view = list.DefaultView;
lvwp.ListId = list.ID;
lvwp.ViewGuid = tabView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
lvwp.ItemContext = SPContext.GetContext(this.Context, view.ID, list.ID, thisWeb);
lvwp.ShowToolbarWithRibbon = true;    
this.Controls.Add(lvwp);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm currently having the same problem. Gary.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the only way to show XsltListViewWebPart ribbon is to add dynamic created webpart to:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="MainZone">
    <ZoneTemplate>

    </ZoneTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your webpart toolbar mode configured as Full? I suppose it may be the case - SharePoint doesn't apply the Ribbon customizations to the list if the webpart toolbar is in Summary mode. Unfortuntely I don't know how to set it programmatically - just point the direction.